# When does the finally gets called in the js Promise context?

Tags: javascript, promise, finally

When does the finally gets called in the js Promise context?

I thought at first that the `finally` will be called after the last `then`. But then I understood that it is impossible to determine the last `then`. Also my attempt below proves that:

```
function f(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("foo");
};
var p = new Promise(f);
p.then(function(data) {
     console.log("data: " + data); 
});
p.finally(function(data) {
     console.log("in finally");
});
p.then(function(data) {
     console.log("data: " + data); 
});
```

Output:

```
data: foo
in finally
data: foo
```

So, the `finally` is not called after the last `then`. And I thought the the `finally` should be called after the `resolve` then. But in the example code I tried above we can see that it is also not the case (because the registered `then` was called between the `resolve` and the `finally`).

Hence, I am confused and can not understand when will the `finally` be called.

Comment: The `finally` callback is called at some point after the promise settles and before the returned promise is resolved. You should not depend on anything else.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.finally` complements `then` and `catch`: `then` block gets called on fulfillment, `catch` gets called on rejection, and `finally` gets called in both cases (for example: you make an API call, in `then` block you process the data, in `catch` block you display error message, in `finally` block you hide the loading spinner).

Then the chain continues.

```js
Promise.reject('execute some action')
  .then(() => console.log('I\'ll handle success here'))
  .catch(() => console.log('error handling'))
  .finally(() => console.log('this block will be executed either way'))
  .then(() => console.log('and the adventure continues'))
```

Comment: Could you, please, change the `compliments` to `complements`?

Answer (score 1):

None of your Promises are chained - everything is connected directly to the root `p` Promise. So when the `p` Promise resolves (or rejects), all `.then` and `.finally` callbacks attached to that Promise run, probably in the order in which they were attached.

In most situations, the Promises will be chained - (eg `.then(() ... ).then` or `.then(() ... ).finally`). Then, the `finally` would run after the previous `.then` completes, *or* after the previous `.then` throws:

```js
function f(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("foo");
};
var p = new Promise(f);
p.then(function(data) {
     console.log("data: " + data); 
})
.finally(function(data) {
     console.log("in finally");
});
```

```js
function f(resolve, reject) {
    resolve("foo");
};
var p = new Promise(f);
p.then(function(data) {
     console.log("data: " + data);
     console.log("About to throw");
     throw new Error();
})
.finally(function(data) { // Above Promise throws, so if this was a .then, it wouldn't run
     console.log("in finally");
});
// No .catch, so this results in an unhandled Promise rejection
```

When deciding when to execute, the `.finally` doesn't look ahead to see if anything is chained off of it - rather, the `.finally` callback executes as soon as the Promise it's called on resolves or rejects.